# How to resolve namespace conflicts when adding a custom control?

Tags: c#, xaml, namespaces, windows-8.1, win-universal-app

I've been following this tutorial [modern UI radial gauge Win 8](http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2013/06/24/A-Modern-UI-radial-gauge-control-for-Windows-8-Store-apps.aspx) in adding a custom gauge control to my Windows 8 project. But I keep getting namespace conflict errors when referencing the control.

Can anyone advise on what the issue could be here / or what steps to take in debugging the conflict?

I tired rebuilding/cleaning/restarting as other solutions on SO suggested, also tried re adding the namespaces and xaml declaration to no avail.

The namespace is declared the same as in the tutorial and the gauge is defined in the same way in my project:

```
xmlns:controls="using:U2UConsult.WinRT.Modern.Controls"

<Border Grid.Row="3"
                Grid.RowSpan="3"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Margin="0"
                Background="Black">
            <controls:Gauge Width="540"
                            Height="320"
                            Maximum="100"
                            Minimum="0"
                            NeedleBrush="Transparent"
                            ScaleBrush="DarkSlateGray"
                            ScaleTickBrush="Black"
                            TickBrush="Transparent"
                            TrailBrush="DarkSeaGreen"
                            Unit="° Fahrenheit"
                            UnitBrush="DarkGray"
                            ValueBrush="DarkSeaGreen"
                            ValueStringFormat="N1"
                            Value="{Binding TotalPoints,
                                            Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </Border>
```

The errors I get are as follows, stating that the Gauge can't be found in the xmlns. The project is targeted to Windows 8.1 but I'm not sure if that would cause the conflict.

```
Error   4   The name "Gauge" does not exist in the namespace "using:U2UConsult.WinRT.Modern.Controls".  

Error   1   The type 'controls:Gauge' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.
```

This is the repo for the Windows 8 part of the universal project for full reference:
[GitHub Repo](https://github.com/BrianJVarley/LC_Points/tree/master/LC%20Points/LC%20Points.Windows)

Comment: Is custom Gauge control added manually? Or are you trying to use control from WinRTXamlToolkit?
I get your repo and I don't see any custom controls (Gauge). There is only reference to WinRTXamlToolkit.

Comment: @marcinax I solved the issue by installing the XAML toolkit instead and adding the below namespace:       xmlns:controls="using:WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls"